# How to compare GMT and EST time from xml using xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery, exist-db

I ran into this problem: I fetch rss feeds from various webpages and then i need to order them by date. I'm using xquery for xml manipulation and eXist database for storing rss/xml.
Here is my code:

```
for $item in subsequence(collection('/db/bla/user/feed')//item[contains(title, $search)], $start, $num)
                 let $title:= $item/title/text()
                 let $desc:= $item/description/text()
                 let $link := $item/link/text()
                 let $date:= $item/pubDate/text()
                 order by $date
```

this does not work. And i assume problem is in different times GMT and EST so order by $date doesn't work as it should.
Please help, I'm stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here is format of date and time which i fetch from pubDate tag:

```
Mon, 10 Dec 2012 13:32:24 EST
```

or

```
Mon, 10 Dec 2012 13:32:24 GMT
```

Comment: It looks like you will need to parse the dateTime. Several APIs have these types of functions built-in: MarkLogic, Java, .NET, etc., so you will have to decide whether you want to parse your dateTime outside of XQuery or write one from scratch in XQuery, in which case that should probably be a different question.

Comment: what version of exist are you using?

Comment: @Ranon I can use version 3.0 and version 1.0 because both versions are supported on eXist db version 2.0 i think... now i'm using 1.0 for my needs

Comment: I didn't care for your XQuery version, but for your eXist dv version; but you answered that, too. See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting `$date` as an actual date/time:

```
let $date:= xs:dateTime($item/pubDate/text())
```

---

If the format of the date/times is consistent, you could implement your own converter. The 2 parts that will give you the most problems, in the example from your comment, is the month and timezone. The month will need to be numerical and you'll need to convert the timezone to the equivalent UTC offset.

Here's an example:

```
declare variable $months := ('jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec');
declare variable $timezoneMap := 
    <map>
        <tz>
            <numeric>-05:00</numeric>
            <alpha>est</alpha>
        </tz>
    </map>;

declare function local:formatDate($origdate as xs:string) as xs:dateTime {
    let $dateTokens := tokenize($origdate,' ')  
    let $timezone := $timezoneMap/tz[lower-case($dateTokens[6])=alpha]/numeric/text()
    let $month := string(index-of($months,lower-case($dateTokens[3])))
    let $newDate := concat($dateTokens[4],'-',if (string-length($month)=1) then concat('0',$month) else $month,'-',$dateTokens[2],
                           'T',$dateTokens[5],$timezone)
    return
        xs:dateTime($newDate)
};
```

You could then use the function like this:

```
let $date:= local:formatDate($item/pubDate)
```

Also, if you're using XQuery 3.0, you could use [maps](http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2012/01/#000188) for the timezone and month:

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
declare variable $months := map{"jan":="01","feb":="02","mar":="03","apr":="04","may":="05","jun":="06",
                                "jul":="07","aug":="08","sep":="09","oct":="10","nov":="11","dec":="12"};
declare variable $timezoneMap := map{"est":="-05:00"};

declare function local:formatDate($origdate as xs:string) as xs:dateTime {
    let $dateTokens := tokenize($origdate,' ')
    let $newDate := concat($dateTokens[4],'-',$months(lower-case($dateTokens[3])),'-',$dateTokens[2],
                           'T',$dateTokens[5],$timezoneMap(lower-case($dateTokens[6])))
    return
        xs:dateTime($newDate)
};
```

Comment: thanks for helping. But it doesn't work. i get this exception: </exception><message><path>....</path>
err:FORG0001: illegal lexical form for date-time-like value 'Mon, 10 Dec 2012 13:32:24 EST' Mon, 10 Dec 2012 13:32:24 EST
</message>
</exception>

Comment: Ahh yeah that's not an xs:dateTime.

Comment: thanks for you effort, your solution looks like it could work but i don't know how can I use it in my case, see my edit for type of my timedate format. How can I modify your solution? thanks

Comment: @user1598696 - My solution works for both examples of time/date in your edit. The only difference is that GMT does not have an offset (which it shouldn't). Both return valid `xs:dateTime`'s. If you have other timezones or month formats in any of your feeds, you'll have to add those. (I can add an example if it would help.)

Comment: I get this error when i try your example: err:FORG0001: illegal lexical form for date-time-like value '2013-1-09T20:23:05-05:00' 2013-1-09T20:23:05-05:00 [at line 22, column 15]
In function:
local:formatDate(xs:string*) [22:15:String] -- What's the problem? Please help. thanks

Comment: @user1598696 - Oops. That's because `index-of()` is returning `1` for January instead of `01`. I'll make an update when I get a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Building some date format parser in XQuery probably isn't the best idea; you will have to deal with all that time zone conversion stuff (and much worse: daylight saving time...) yourself.

## The official way: DateTime-Module

eXist DB has its own DateTime-Module based on [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The module must be compiled and activated before using it and is not included in eXists current stable release (but in 1.4.3 developer release and version 2 pre-release).

Caveat, it uses your system's default locale, which in my case wasn't english (so recognizing the dates failed miserably).

If you managed enabling it (if you don't, this is probably another question on [Database Administrator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), a SO sister site), you should be able to run this code to parse dates in the format given:

```
import module namespace datetime = "http://exist-db.org/xquery/datetime";
datetime:parse-dateTime('Mon, 10 Dec 2012 13:32:24 GMT', 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z')
```

## The Dirty Hack: Interfacing Java

If you're running some older version of eXist or cannot use the module for other reasons, you could activate Java bindings in `conf.xml` and call this function directly:

```
declare namespace sdtf="java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat";
declare namespace date="java:java.util.Date";

(: Parse given date format to java date :)    
let $parse := sdtf:new('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z')
(: Output as close to XQuery's xs:dateTime as possible :)
let $format := sdtf:new("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
let $javadate := sdtf:parse($parse, 'Mon, 10 Dec 2012 13:32:24 GMT')
(: Use regex to insert missing ':' and finally cast to xs:dateTime :)
return xs:dateTime(fn:replace(sdtf:format($format, $javadate), '(.*)(\d{2})', '$1:$2'))
```

Again, remember to set java locale to english if it isn't by default.

*I guess this should be running fine in at least Saxon (which defined this java binding) and BaseX (I actually tested it in here).*

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ryan Grimm's XQuery-based Date Parser module.  It's built for MarkLogic but with small modifications should work on other systems too.  See https://github.com/marklogic/commons/blob/master/dates/date-parser.xqy.

As the comments in the module state, its supported date formats are:

1. 30 Jun 2006 09:39:08 -0500
2. Apr 16 13:49:06 2003 +0200
3. Aug 04 11:44:58 EDT 2003
4. 4 Jan 98 0:41 EDT
5. 25-Oct-2004 17:06:46 -0500
6. Mon, 23 Sep 0102 23:14:26 +0900